# Disable Crashlytics Build Id automatic generation

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics, google-fabric

I need to disable Crashlytics `build_id` automatic generation every time I assemble a new build because of CI requirements.

According to [fabric docs](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/build-tools.html#optimize-builds-when-you-re-not-proguarding-or-using-beta-by-crashlytics), it's as simple as adding the next flag inside my build type:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
          ext.alwaysUpdateBuildId = false
          ...
        }

        release {
          ext.alwaysUpdateBuildId = false
          ...
        }
```

But for some reasons it's only working for `debug` builds and not on the `release` ones.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In documentation stands: We only recommend doing this if you’re not Proguarding or using Beta by Crashlytics, otherwise your crashes may not be deobfuscated correctly. Isn't this your issue?

Comment: #Impotant note
"ext.alwaysUpdatedBuildId is not aware of build variants. Whichever value is set last in the build.gradle is the one that will be used."

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine in the latest version of Fabric Gradle plugin